# Finding all integers $m$ such that $a^m = a^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here, $a$ is an element of some group $G$ of order $n$. Of course, I know that $a^n = e$ and that $a^m = e$ if and only if the order of $a$ divides $m$. These are the only statements from the lecture that seem relevant to this problem, but I'm not sure how to use them. The only thing I could think of was that $a^m$ might be equal to some $a^p*a^l = e = a^l*a^p$, but I'm not sure where that leads me either. I'm at a complete standstill.

Comment: $a^ma=e\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

$a^m=a^{-1}$ implies $a^{m+1}=e$, so $m=-1\bmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miswrote, $a^m=e$ only if $n|m$. So conside the equation $a^m=e$ and multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ and we get 
$$a^ma^{-1}=a^{m-1}=ea^{-1}=a^{-1}$$
with $m$ being a multiple of $n$ still. As such we get the integers to be $pn-1$ with $p$ being any integer.